# XSD - xs:nonNegativeInteger and values ending with .00

Tags: xsd, integer, decimal

I realize that the value 0.00 is not a valid nonNegativeInteger, nor is it even an Integer.
Unfortunately, the data is coming in that format.  I don't want to throw it away if it ends with .0 but, I also don't want to change the type to Decimal and possibly have values ending in .1 coming in as valid.

Is there a way my XSD can validate numbers such that they are just positive whole numbers, so values of 0.00, 0, 1, 1.0, 2.0000000 etc are all accepted, but -1, 1.1, 2.2, 3.3333 are all invalid?

Thanks
-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at changing to decimal and placing a restriction on the places after the decimal point. In particular, you might be able to use a regex facet. I've never tried this, and don't even know if it's valid, but it's a direction to look at. You'd be restricting the lexical space rather than the value space, but that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This works for what I need, thanks John

```
<xs:simpleType name="nonNegativeWholeDecimal">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
        <xs:pattern value="[0-9]*(\.[0]*)?"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```